# How do I blur a CGImage, or UIImageView

Tags: iphone, uiimageview, blur, cgimage

I have a UIImageView with a .png inside it. I want to blur the image during runtime. How do I do that?

Comment: Your question is pretty vague

Comment: I asked this 9 years ago, I was first learning to code. I was only trying to blur an image in a `UIImageView`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want something like a Gaussian Blur which you can google for loads of information and algorithms. I also found [How to implement a box or gaussian blur on iphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1140117/how-to-implement-a-box-or-gaussian-blur-on-iphone) post for you which has some tricks for the iPhone.