# How do I add a user background into the app with a blur effect in iOS 7?

Tags: ios, xcode

Basically I want to know if it's possible to add an effect similar to when you open Newsstand with no magazines and you encounter an effect where you can kind of see the user wallpaper with a blur effect added onto it. 
I sort of managed to get the wallpaper onto the app with a few .plist settings changes, but want to know if theres a better way that also adds the blur effect.

regards,
Patricio

Comment: take a look [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11601166/iphone-sdk-frosted-glass-ios-7-blur-effect) and yes you still not given response of your [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18929864/how-do-i-change-the-navigation-bar-color-in-ios-7/18930242#18930242)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `UIImage` category that Apple provides in its sample code, that allows you to blur a `UIImage` with a variety of styles and colours.

https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action?name=WWDC%202013

Search the page for `UIImageEffects`, download it. Open the project, and you'll find a `UIImage` category you can move to your project.

More on this topic can be found in the Engaging UIs in iOS7 WWDC 2013 talk.