# Frosted glass effect in SpriteKit?

Tags: ios, xcode, sprite-kit

I'm trying to add frosted glass effect for nodes in my game. For example http://bit.ly/1vNMvAG
What is the right way to do that?

Comment: Blur filter makes something like this [link](http://bit.ly/1rDorCR) But I need to blur everything behind the node. Something like "blur mask".

Comment: @CHBuckingham I need to blur the scene behind the node. I won't get this effect while blurring white texture.

Comment: @CHBuckingham This illustrates the difference: [link](http://bit.ly/1xCcgXr) Or I didn't understand you?

Comment: Removing comments and just putting a step by step in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I must be missing something, as I would just stay with SpriteKit, as suggested in original comments, but maybe I'll get schooled and learn something new. :-) *EDIT*, simplified everything, and now you can just move the crop mask by setting it as a property and then changing its position dynamically as you go. Obviously you could jazz it up with various sprite layers.

```
SKSpriteNode *bgImage = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"bgImage.png"];
bgImage.anchorPoint = CGPointZero;
[self addChild:bgImage];

cropMaskNode = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"clippingImage.png"];

SKCropNode *cropNode = [SKCropNode node];

SKSpriteNode *bgInsideOfCrop = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"bgImage.png"];
bgInsideOfCrop.anchorPoint = CGPointZero;
SKEffectNode *effectNode = [SKEffectNode node];
effectNode.filter = [self blurFilter];
effectNode.shouldEnableEffects = YES;
effectNode.shouldCenterFilter = YES;
effectNode.shouldRasterize = YES;

[self addChild: cropNode];
[effectNode addChild:bgInsideOfCrop];
[cropNode addChild:effectNode];
cropNode.maskNode = cropMaskNode;
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work. I just see transparent node.

Comment: I can't help you if you don't help yourself. The code above works great. I don't know what "only see a transparent node means". But it sounds like you missed a step.

Comment: I need something like iOS7 effect. There is UIToolbar in UIKit and I can change its shape using CALayer, but its not real to mix it with SpriteKit.

Comment: It sounds like you're still confused. I can't go back in forth in comments again. I took the time to give you a pretty great step by step solution. You can tailor it with however you'd like your blur effect plus an optional frosted layer to look. I wish you the best of luck. :-)

Comment: This is the correct approach in my opinion, thanks for posting it!

Answer (score 0):

this effect is only available in ios 7 to my knowlwdge. Engin Kurutepe has posted it on [Github](https://github.com/ekurutepe/iOS-Blur-Examples)

```
- (void)willMoveToSuperview:(UIView *)newSuperview
{
    [super willMoveToSuperview:newSuperview];
    if (newSuperview == nil) {
        return;
    }
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newSuperview.bounds.size, YES, 0.0);
    [newSuperview drawViewHierarchyInRect:newSuperview.bounds afterScreenUpdates:YES];
    UIImage *img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIImage *croppedImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:CGImageCreateWithImageInRect(img.CGImage, self.frame)];
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    self.backgroundImage = [croppedImage applyBlurWithRadius:11
                                                   tintColor:[UIColor colorWithWhite:1 alpha:0.3]
                                       saturationDeltaFactor:1.8
                                                   maskImage:nil];
}
```

[Code Sample Ref](http://www.kurutepe.com/2014/04/ios-blur-part1/)

Comment: update: if you are not using the ios 7 sdk then check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11601166/iphone-sdk-frosted-glass-ios-7-blur-effect

Comment: But it is for UIView. How can I apply blur for SKSpriteNode?

Comment: i guess the workaround would be to do something like var overlay = UIView(new RectangleF(0,0, 100, 100));

overlay.AddSubviews(...)

Comment: Thank you! I've added blurred UIImage as a texture of SKSpriteNode and it works good.

Comment: @user3785463 that's great! knew there had to be a way!

Comment: Unfortunately, this method is good for static background, but not for dynamic.