# iphone interface glow effect question

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, interface, effects, glow

I'd like to achieve the glow effect on what I believe are UILabels (or maybe a custom control?) in this application called convert. I think the app looks pretty neat and I'm trying to achieve a similar effect for my own application

Any help?

Best regards
david

[alt text http://www.davidhomes.net/convert.png](http://www.davidhomes.net/convert.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The applicatin seems to have the glow effect only for numbers. That's 10 digits plus a few symbols (".", "+", "-", etc). An easy way to achieve this is to have a different image for each digit and symbol, and create a subclass of `UIView` that can draw numbers in its `drawDect` method.

Answer (score 8):

In my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1229721/is-there-an-easy-way-or-library-available-to-let-text-glow/1230907#1230907), I describe a way to apply a glow effect to any text or vector elements drawn within a UIView or CALayer.

Comment: Brad, please don't go 100% moderator on us! Answers like this make Stack Overflow for Objective-C users. +1 for the link, thanks.