# How to get a glow effect in Quartz for the iphone?

Tags: iphone, xcode, sdk, quartz-2d, glow

I am searching for a glow effect in quartz 2d for the iphone. I tried making lines with different alpha values to simulate glow but it didn't work...

Can anyone help me with that ??

p.s.
I'm making an app where the user can draw with glow. I have the basic lines, but no glow :(

Comment: possible duplicate of [iphone interface glow effect question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1252653/iphone-interface-glow-effect-question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, the Core Animation / Quartz 2D Compositing filters are currently not available in iOS.
http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CALayer_class/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/CALayer/compositingFilter, chapter: Special Considerations

But there may be some other ways you could achieve your glow effect using shadows: [Adding glowing effect to the circle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1464283/adding-glowing-effect-to-the-circle) 
I hope this helped, kind regards...