# Making Glow effect to font

Tags: ios

I wonder if anybody have an example for Glow effect for font? I tried to look in NSAttributedString but I don't find in attribute for glowing text.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there an easy way or library available to let text glow?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1229721/is-there-an-easy-way-or-library-available-to-let-text-glow)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
#include <Quartzcore/Quartzcore.h>
.......
yourLabel.layer.shadowColor = [[UIColor glowColor] CGColor]; //Replace glowColor with the desired color (redColor, greenColor, etc.)
yourLabel.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0.0, 0.0); //The glow starts from the center

yourLabel.layer.shadowRadius = 20.0; //You can change this to the desired amount
yourLabel.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5; //You can change this to the desired amount

yourLabel.layer.masksToBounds = NO; //Keep this the same to avoid shadow being clipped by the label bounds
```

Hope this helps!