# How To Blur Image edges in Iphone

Tags: iphone, uiscrollview, blur, edges

I have three UIImages added to three UIScrollviews that are positioned one under the other.
I am trying to find a way to blur the adjacent edges that are between two scrollviews but am unable to find a way to do that.

Can someone please suggest a way to achieve this?

Any help will be appreciated

Thank You

Shumais Ul Haq

Answer (score 0):

You could do some gaussian blurring on an image. This has been asked [before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/227305/how-do-i-create-blurred-text-in-an-iphone-view).

```
static void blur(V2fT2f *quad, float t) // t = 1
{
    GLint tex;
    V2fT2f tmpquad[4];
    float offw = t / Input.wide;
    float offh = t / Input.high;
    int i;

    glGetIntegerv(GL_TEXTURE_BINDING_2D, &tex);

    // Three pass small blur, using rotated pattern to sample 17 texels:
    //
    // .\/.. 
    // ./\\/ 
    // \/X/\   rotated samples filter across texel corners
    // /\\/. 
    // ../\. 

    // Pass one: center nearest sample
    glVertexPointer  (2, GL_FLOAT, sizeof(V2fT2f), &quad[0].x);
    glTexCoordPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, sizeof(V2fT2f), &quad[0].s);
    glTexEnvi(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_MODULATE);
    glColor4f(1.0/5, 1.0/5, 1.0/5, 1.0);
    validateTexEnv();
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);

    // Pass two: accumulate two rotated linear samples
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glEnable(GL_BLEND);
    glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE);
    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        tmpquad[i].x = quad[i].s + 1.5 * offw;
        tmpquad[i].y = quad[i].t + 0.5 * offh;
        tmpquad[i].s = quad[i].s - 1.5 * offw;
        tmpquad[i].t = quad[i].t - 0.5 * offh;
    }
    glTexCoordPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, sizeof(V2fT2f), &tmpquad[0].x);
    glTexEnvi(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_REPLACE);
    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE1);
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glClientActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE1);
    glTexCoordPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, sizeof(V2fT2f), &tmpquad[0].s);
    glEnableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, tex);
    glTexEnvi(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_COMBINE);
    glTexEnvi(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_COMBINE_RGB,      GL_INTERPOLATE);
    glTexEnvi(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_SRC0_RGB,         GL_TEXTURE);
    glTexEnvi(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_SRC1_RGB,         GL_PREVIOUS);
    glTexEnvi(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_SRC2_RGB,         GL_PRIMARY_COLOR);
    glTexEnvi(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_OPERAND2_RGB,     GL_SRC_COLOR);
    glTexEnvi(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_COMBINE_ALPHA,    GL_REPLACE);
    glTexEnvi(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_SRC0_ALPHA,       GL_PRIMARY_COLOR);

    glColor4f(0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 2.0/5);
    validateTexEnv();
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);

    // Pass three: accumulate two rotated linear samples
    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        tmpquad[i].x = quad[i].s - 0.5 * offw;
        tmpquad[i].y = quad[i].t + 1.5 * offh;
        tmpquad[i].s = quad[i].s + 0.5 * offw;
        tmpquad[i].t = quad[i].t - 1.5 * offh;
    }
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);

    // Restore state
    glDisableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
    glClientActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, Half.texID);
    glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glTexEnvi(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_OPERAND2_RGB,     GL_SRC_ALPHA);
    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
    glDisable(GL_BLEND);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for you reply.
I have read the thread that youhave linked to. From what I understand, it is blurring the whole image. That is not what I am looking for.

I need to blur the edges of contents of the a scrollview, it does not matter what part of the imaeg is displayed, i need to have blurred edges of the displayed parts of the image.

I am trying to blur the edges between two scroll views...so if A is first scrollview and B is the second and they are displayed as AAAABBB, then i would like to have the AB in the middle to be blurred.

I hope that my question is clearer now.

Thank You!

Comment: That's how you do blurring. So apply that knowledge on that edges :)

Comment: just crop the original image and paste it on top of the blurred one, and you have blurred edges

Answer (score 0):

You can use CALayer.mask to set a "mask layer" to add transparent regions. Set this on the scroll view (e.g. `#import <QuartzCore/CALayer.h> ... scrollView.layer.mask = whatever`) to give the edges more transparency.

I can't remember if layer masks are automatically resized. They also perform particularly poorly on older (e.g. 3G) devices. It might do what you want, though.

Comment: Thank you. I will look into it, hopefully it can do what i need.

Thanks once again!

Comment: @tc can you please explain a little more or give some sample code Thanx